# PYlab is not working on my Enthought python

Tags: python, matplotlib

My PYlab is showing the following error:

That the PYlab ipython module has stopped working.

Even a simple plot like `plot({1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7])` is not working.  (sorry I wanted to add images or the error but stackoverflow has prevented me from doing it.)  The actual problem is that the iPython shell for the pylab is starting but any I literally mean any plot is not working.

Not even a simple plot is showing. I am using Enthought python shell with python version :2.7
and using windows xp sp2 32-bit as my OS. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it throwing an error or just not appearing? Could you show an example of code (yours has a basic syntax error), and explain exactly how it is not working?

Comment: Copy-and-paste the code and error messages as text. Alternatively, post a link to the images and somebody with a higher reputation can edit them into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `plot({1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7])` it should be `plot([1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7])`. Also did you import pylab or ( matplotlib and numpy)?

Your code should be something like:

```
 import pylab as pl
 pl.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7])
```